# What is this 'method-like' syntax in JS object literal

Tags: javascript, syntax, object-literal

Use ES6 class sugar, we can define function this way:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(props) {}
  ...
  myFn() {}     
}
```

and in JS object literal, we can define *getters* and *setters* like this:

```
foo = {
  get data() {}
  set data(val) {}
}
```

However, what's this syntax:

```
foo = {
  data() {}
}
```

Is this object data properties? Or getters/setters?

<sub>note: this syntax is extensively used in Vue.js 2.0 doc, like the new added `render` function.</sub>

```
new Vue({
  render (h) {
    throw new Error('oops')
  },
  renderError (h, err) {
    return h('pre', { style: { color: 'red' }}, err.stack)
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its just shorthand. [refer to MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
// Shorthand method names (ES2015)
var o = {
  // doesnt need a colon!
  property([parameters]) {},
  get property() {},
  set property(value) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! What a fool question （─.─||）, easily lost when es5 and es6 get messed up.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = {
  data() {}
}
```

is short hand for

```
foo = {
  data: function() {}
}
```