# How do I interpret this syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I found this snippet of code online:

```js
function cjsDetectionPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'cjs-detection',
    moduleParsed({
      id,
      meta: {
        commonjs: { isCommonJS }
      }
    }) {
      console.log(`File ${id} is CommonJS: ${isCommonJS}`);
    }
  };
}
```

I understand that this is perfectly valid JS, but it just doesn't compute in my head.
The method `cjsDetectionPlugin` is returning an object, but what exactly is happening on the line with `moduleParsed`? Does this resolve into some sort of property name?

And my biggest question is how this object can have a sub-property that calls code (`console.log...`).

What's going on here? Where can I find the definition for this specific syntax as to learn learn more about it?

Comment: It's a function declaration (well, a method) that uses object destructuring in the formal parameter list.

Comment: Does this answer your question [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses): `5. To extract values from parameters into standalone variables` in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Pointy I am familiar with object destructuring, but the line with `moduleParsed` doesn't look like a function declaration to me, but a function *call*. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's the syntax (fairly new) for declaring a property in an object with a function as it's value. Basically it's like `x: function x() { ... }` in the old syntax.

Comment: Either the method wants to return an object (`return {...`) or it wants to print out a line in the console. Which is it? :)

Comment: @silkfire It is a [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) so it is a duplicate to [What is this 'method-like' syntax in JS object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561740/3001761) in combination with `5. To extract values from parameters into standalone variable`  of my earlier comment.

Comment: `cjsDetectionPlugin` returns an object with a property `name` and a method definition `moduleParsed`, and the method `moduleParsed` calls `console.log`.

Comment: @Pointy Oh I see. So its property name is `moduleParsed`? I thought function declarations needed to have a head, like `x: () => moduleParsed(...)`

Comment: @silkfire just follow the links it is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), refer to the "Unpacking properties from objects passed as a function parameter
" section in shared link

following one is using object destructering in function parameter:

```
function sayMyName({ name }) {
    console.log(`my name is ${name}`);
}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
function sayMyName(person) {
    console.log(`my name is ${person.name}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a [MDN: Method declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```
function cjsDetectionPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'cjs-detection',
    moduleParsed() {
      console.log('some logs');
    }
  };
}
```

And [MDN: Destructuring assignment: Unpacking properties from objects passed as a function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter):

```
function moduleParsed(/*begin: parameters*/{
  id,
  meta: {
     commonjs: { isCommonJS }
  }
}/*end: parameters*/) {
      console.log(`File ${id} is CommonJS: ${isCommonJS}`);
}
```